# How do I "next()" my way into the error handler in this project?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run a test that says

```
test("POST /register, malformed and edge cases", async () => {
            await request(server).post(`/auth/register`).expect(400);
        });
```

I am sending an empty request body. My goal is to trigger the error handler to respond with some sort of 4xx status code.

I am working using the boilerplate in this blog: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/13/node-mongo-api-with-email-sign-up-verification-authentication-forgot-password

Here's what I'm doing:

1. I hit this route with a POST request: `this.router.post("/register", registerUserSchema, this.register);`
   I expect that the `registerUserSchema` is engaged and indeed it is. I can tell because a console.log statement happens. Then

```
function registerUserSchema(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const schema: ObjectSchema<any> = Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
        confirmPassword: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref("password")).required(),
        acceptTerms: Joi.boolean().valid(true).required(),
    });
    validateRequest(req, next, schema);
}
```

2. the function downstream of `registerUserSchema` is this: `validateRequest(req, next, schema);` which does occur as I expedct, leading to
3. this

```
function validateRequest(req: Request, next: NextFunction, schema: ObjectSchema<any>) {
    const options = {
        abortEarly: false, // include all errors
        allowUnknown: true, // ignore unknown props
        stripUnknown: true, // remove unknown props
    };
    const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body, options);
    console.log(error, "12rm");
    if (error) {
        next(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message.replaceAll('"', "")).join(", ")}`);
        // next(error);
    } else {
        req.body = value;
        next();
    }
}
export default validateRequest;
```

I know that this "Validation error:" text makes it out of the server because it shows up in Postman.

However, what I really want is to be able to *modify the status code from 500 to 4xx*. I presumed this errorHandler would do it because I say `this.app.use(errorHandler);` in my app.ts file. But it doesn't happen, my console.log doesn't do anything during a malformed request to `/auth/register`

```
function errorHandler(err: any, request: Request, response: Response) {
    console.log("In the error handler, 5rm", err, typeof err);
}
```

If someone can enlighten me: How do I anticipate where `next()` will activate next in my application?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution was

```
   const err = new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map(x => x.message.replaceAll('"', "")).join(", ")}`);
        err.name = "ValidationError";
        next(err);
```

then the error handler figured out it was next as I expected it to